# What is "overlay" in sublime text editor?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

What is the "overlay" in ST and how can it be used?  (please indicate default key bindings)

Answer (score 4):

It's just a generic interface element which pops up a list of options and a field for searching them. Examples of overlays include the [command palette](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/command_palette.html) (Ctrl+Shift+P) and [Goto Anything](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#goto-anything) (Ctrl+P).

Answer (score -1):

Do you talking about command which by default binded to "ctrl+;"?
As far as i know it works like find(ctrl+f), but overlay can search for one word only.
For example we have this file:

```
Someone correct my english pls
```

If we will use find command we could look for more than one word like "my english".
But if we gonna use overlay we could to search for "my" or "english" only.
We can't search with overlay for "my engligh" cuz here is more than one word.

Answer (score -2):

Sublime Text can read settings from multiple configuration files.

[The default order is described here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html).

```
Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings
Packages/Default/Preferences (<platform>).sublime-settings
Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
<Project Settings>
Packages/<syntax>/<syntax>.sublime-settings
Packages/User/<syntax>.sublime-settings
<Buffer Specific Settings>
```

The latter configuration files override ("overlay") the former, allowing you to have more specific settings for certain programming language, project, etc.